# How to get dragged point on the DirectionsRenderer

Tags: google-maps

I use google maps for drawing my route. I setup only 2 points (start and end). The problem is that I will have to send the route to the next page.

I know that I can catch event:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
            $("#full-route-json").val(encode64(JSON.stringify(directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0])));
        });
```

But it will return all steps. 
How to get the data only for my start and end points and dragged point like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no implemented method to access these points(markers).

But these markers are stored  inside a property of the DirectionsRenderer-instance.

The following code will give you these detail(please note that this code works now, but it may fail when the API changes)

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    var that=this;
    setTimeout(function(){//we need a short delay
      for(var k in that){//iterate over all properties
        if(typeof that[k].markers!='undefined'){//find the desired property
          var markers=that[k].markers,arr=[];
          for(var i=0;i<markers.length;++i){//collect the data
            arr.push(markers[i].position.toString());
        }
        alert(arr.join(',\n'));
      }
    }},100)
  });
```