# Display Label for Each Waypoint Pin on Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, label, google-maps-markers, map-directions

I'm trying to add a label for each waypoint along the route, but I'm not quite sure how I should approach it. After doing some research, I understand that you can add a custom pin with label, but that's when I drop each pin manually. How can I do this for direction?

Comment: [custom markers on results of (multiple) directions request(s)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html)

Comment: I actually ended up suppressing the markers and add them manually since there is no way to get a reference to the pins dropped by direction service.

Comment: That is how the linked example works.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664480/how-to-get-dragged-point-on-the-directionsrenderer/18667822#18667822 to see how you may access the markers created by the DirectionsRenderer

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get access to markers from DirectionsRenderer request that need a hack because there is not official way to do this from google map api.

There is a way around, here is an example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/TomKarachristos/cna78jbw/

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', 
    function() {
        var self = this;
        markersArray = []; //empty the array
        setTimeout(function() { //wait until markers render
          for (var k in self) { //search everything in directionsDisplay
            if (typeof self[k].markers != 'undefined') { //  its that the markers?
              var markers = self[k].markers;
              for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
                markersArray.push(markers[i]);
                markersArray[i].setLabel({ //lets change the label!
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: "16px",
                  text: i.toString()
                });
              }
            }
          }
          console.log(markersArray); // now markersArray have all the markers 
        }, 0);
      });
```

But this is not a good solution if you want full control of markers. If you supress the markers you have many possibilities, you can use markers from libraries like [markerLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/) or [RichMarker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker)(use a dom element for marker!)

Here an example with markerLabel, you click anywhere in the map and a marker appear with a label with the distance from the center marker.
https://jsfiddle.net/TomKarachristos/x1zg503m/

```
[...]
 markerArray[1] = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, //just for fun
    labelContent: "",
    labelClass: "marker-label"
  });
[...]
if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      route = directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0];
      markerArray[1].set('labelContent', route.legs[0].distance.value / 1000)
[...]
```

more easy to make, more nice to see, more fun!
[image]