# How to show duration popup on polyline?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I want to show route duration on `Polyline` as shown on the screenshot. I have done some digging on internet but couldn't find the solution.

[image: screenshot]

Guide me if anyone of you have any solution.
Thanks.

Comment: refers these links https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes

Comment: Need details in brief please. There's nothing about these dialog/popups.

Comment: Have a look for reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770599/display-label-for-each-waypoint-pin-on-google-map-api

Comment: Also this link will helpful : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?csw=1

Answer (score 0):

you can show markers according to locations and markers have their own info windows 
refer to this link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows

Comment: Info windows are always anchored to a marker. I want to anchor it to `Polyline`.

Comment: You can use [Symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#properties) if you want to add image in your polyline. A symbol is a vector-based image defined by a path, using SVG path notation. To [add a symbol to a polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#add_to_polyline), set the `icons[]` property of the `PolylineOptions` object. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247145/how-to-put-a-infowindow-on-polyline-in-google-maps-v3) might also help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Direction API to get the route and draw the polyline

Add OnPolylineClickListener in Map and get the reference using getTag

```
    mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
            Log.e("Polyline position", " -- " + polyline.getTag());
            onButtonShowPopupWindowClick("  " + polyline.getTag());
        }
    });
```

Set any reference in polyline using setTag method

```
                Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
                line.setTag("" + i);
                line.setClickable(true);
```

Open PopupWindow in polyline click

```
public void onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(String count) {

    String[] timeDistance = count.split(",");

    // get a reference to the already created main layout
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)
            findViewById(R.id.whole_layout);

    // inflate the layout of the popup window
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.polyline_window, null);

    ((TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.time)).setText("30 mins");
    ((TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.distance)).setText("20 km");

    // create the popup window
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

    // show the popup window
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    // dismiss the popup window when touched
    popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```